# Writing data to a text file from Arduino using Processing

Tags: arduino, processing

I am currently trying to get a value (`Yes!`) from the Arduino to a text file (`data.txt`).

The problem is that the data isn't being read from the Arduino's Serial. When I tried to simple print the value to the prompt in `processing`, I came out empty handed.

Below is my code for the Arduino

```java
//Just a basic program to write to the Serial the word/phrase; `Yes!`.

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("Yes!");
}
```

Below is my code for `processing`:

```java
import processing.serial.*;
Serial mySerial;
PrintWriter output;
void setup() {
   mySerial = new Serial( this, Serial.list()[0], 9600 );
   output = createWriter( "data.txt" );
}
void draw() {
    if (mySerial.available() > 0 ) {
         String value = mySerial.readString();
         if ( value != null ) {
              output.println( value );
         }
    }
}

void keyPressed() {
    output.flush();  // Writes the remaining data to the file
    output.close();  // Finishes the file
    exit();  // Stops the program
}
```

Yes, this code was found from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480737/how-to-write-data-to-a-text-file-on-arduino) `stackoverflow` question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're going to have to do some debugging. Are you sure you only have one serial connection? What is returned from `Serial.list()`? Which `if` statement isn't entered? Use print statements to find out. What happens if you just print to the console instead of to a file?

Comment: Nothing happens when I print to the console, it isn't reading the values properly. What would happen if I have more than one serial connection?

Comment: What is the length of the array returned by `Serial.list()`? Which `if` statement is not entered?

Comment: Wow, that was really stupid of me. I was calling COM1, instead of my intended COM3 while using Serial.list(). Thanks @KevinWorkman!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this line:

```
mySerial = new Serial( this, Serial.list()[0], 9600 );
```

This line assumes you only have one serial connection. If you have more than one serial connection, you're going to have to change the hard-coded index being used in this line.

Comment: Just had to change the hard coded 0 to a 1. If your looking for the COM port, keep on printing the value to the console or simply hard code the com you want.