# How to write data to a text file then send to FTP Server on Arduino ESP32

Tags: arduino

I know to write data on Arduino could be done by monitoring Serial interface then write the output data to text file. Previously asked in this thread: [How to write data to a text file on Arduino?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480737/how-to-write-data-to-a-text-file-on-arduino)

The text file could be save on SD card or SPIFFS ESP file system ([SPIFFS: Writing a file](https://techtutorialsx.com/2018/08/05/esp32-arduino-spiffs-writing-a-file)).

But how to send the text file from ESP32 to FTP server?

Is it possible to directly write the text file to FTP server with wifi connection?

Tried FTP example from [Arduino Playground](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/FTP) seems doesn't work on ESP32, the Arduino IDE 1.8.7 gives me a bunch of errors.

[Compiler errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzQrM.jpg)

Tried to Google entire internet, didn't found anything. There is many FTP Server source code example for ESP32 but nothing about ESP32 as FTP client.

Please help.

Comment: you didn't change the Playground code from Ethernet library to ESP32 WiFi library?!

Comment: Tried to change the library to suit with the ESP32 but failed, the Arduino IDE compiler still gave me tons of errors. I am not real expert programmer, just copy & paste programmer.

Comment: Finally found working FTP client code for ESP32, partially answer my own question above. The working ESP32 FTP client code can be found in here: [How to write some string into text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584103/how-to-write-some-string-into-text-file)

Comment: The final answer to the question is a dead link. But I wrote a small and simple library to write textfiles or images via FTP some time ago to log the data of my temperature sensors. I wrote a small example with a `.ino` file on how to use it for textfiles. I kept this very basic so maybe it helps. You can find it here:
[ESP32_FTPClient](https://github.com/blackcodetavern/ESP32_FTPClient)